# How to implement Security/Authentication with WCF and Android. Please Include examples

Tags: android, wcf, security, authentication

I have a Wcf web service and an android application that makes calls to the service methods. It is a requirement that some sort of authentication take place, preferably with a username/password combo. The data is not sensitive but I just need to make the service only accessible from the android application. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have multiple methods very similar to this

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse, UriTemplate:="endpoint?busUnit={busUnit}")> _
Function lstJobsSVC(busUnit As String) As List(Of JobsView)
```

Then I implement the method in the service as follows

```
Public Function lstJobsSVC(busUnit As String) As List(Of JobsView) Implements IService1.lstJobsSVC
    Dim entities As New RemoteTimeEntities()
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"

    Return entities.lstJobs(busUnit).ToList
End Function
```

And then in android

```
URL json = new URL("http://localhost/json/Service1.svc/"+ "functions endpoint";                 
                HttpURLConnection jc = (HttpURLConnection) json.openConnection();                   
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jc.getInputStream()));
                readLine = reader.readLine();
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(readLine);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("get json array name");
```

Now All of this code works fine I just do not understand how to implement authentication that will work between the two.

Comment: Not exactly sure what the down vote was for but I've made the requested changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you got the calls itself working correctly. If so, the simplest (yet secure enough) method to *authenticate clients* would be:

1. Client sends login and SHA-1 or SHA-256 hash of the password (do not use other hash algorithms - until you know it better. SHA-256 option is better)
2. Server finds the corresponding password hash of that user and compares it with the value sent by client. If the hash is the same, everything's fine.

This method requires an SSL connection to be fully secure (to protect against eavesdropping/replay attacks)

If you need to restrict the data to *android app only*, you need to encrypt the payload with the AES key known only by both server and client applications. Use only CBC or CTR modes.

You can combine both methods if needed. But keep in mind that security is a very tough matter, and the approaches I've described are only "so good". Don't put confidential info in the app, if you don't know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I have now implemented a hash function in both my service and my app. But what I dont Understand is what keeps some one who connects to the server from going to a browser and typing something like http://server/myService/functionName/userName/Hashcode and then they would have access?
how is the different from  http://server/myService/functionName/userName/pword
Clearly im missing something here

Comment: Guessing a SHA-256 hash is baically the same as guessing a 256-bit encryption key. Never gonna happen. One more advice: *never* put login parameters in URL, use POST method or move it to internal payload.

Comment: Ahh Thank you using POST and not GET was the piece that I was missing.

Comment: can you provide an example of method 1 or 2